# How to uppercase regexp result in sublime or notepad ++

Tags: regex

I'm starting to learn regexp and I need some help.
How can I convert to uppercase the result of my search with "sublime text" or notepad ++ ?

I need to search for a string using a regexp.

For example, in this text:

```
  if :demandes.status ='B' 
     then :demandes.proj_no := null;
     :demandes.autori_d := null;
```

the result of my find action should be:
":demandes.proj_no" and ":demandes.autori_d"

After that, I need to convert this result to upper case, so I should obtain something like this:

```
  if :DEMANDES.STATUS ='B' 
      then :DEMANDES.PROJ_NO := null;
      :DEMANDES.AUTORI_D := null;
```

I tried this with Sublime text:

```
Find what:  (demandes.)([a-z]+)(_)([a-z]+)

Replace with: "\U$1\2\4"
```

but it doesn't work as expected.

Any thoughts will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can modify your syntax as follows:

```
Find What: (demandes\.\w+)
Replace With: \U\1
```